# Create localized .zip file to be uploaded on Blackberry app world

Tags: blackberry, localization, publish, blackberry-world

I need to create .zip file to be uploaded on Blackberry (App) World, but the instructions on [the Blackberry page](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/47831/664046.jsp) seem to be very confusing.

I have 3 bundles, support for OS version 4.6, support for OS version 4.7 and up, support for 6.0 and up. I need to support two languages (English and Spanish).

To do that do I need to create 2 bundles for each OS version? One for English and one for Spanish? Do I also need to add a suffix on each .cod file per bundle to support the languages that I need to support?

Comment: Further to Nate's answer, I would ignore the suggestion to create a zip file.  I did that once, and it took more time to create the zip file than to just upload the files manually.  And it was confusing, where as when I did it manually it was clear which file was going in which bundle and which bundle was for which OS.  So try the manual upload.

Comment: Too bad my boss just ask me to provide the .zip file, he is the one who will upload it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...do I need to create 2 bundles for each os version?

It depends how you want to do it.

### Single-Language Bundles

If the English and Spanish versions have **large** differences, then you might find yourself using different images, possibly even different UI layouts, in addition to simply changing the language of your text.   In that situation, you might want to provide a different bundle for each language (so you would have 3 English bundles and 3 Spanish bundles).  That file structure might look like this:

```
 - MyApp_2.0
    - release.xml
    - MyAppNoTouchEnglish_4.6.0.0
      - devices.txt
      - <.cod files go here>
    + MyAppNoTouchSpanish_4.6.0.0
    + MyAppTouchEnglish_4.7.0.0
    + MyAppTouchSpanish_4.7.0.0
    + MyAppTouchEnglish_6.0.0.0
    + MyAppTouchSpanish_6.0.0.0
```

Then, in the top-level release.xml file, you would need to [identify the language codes of your bundles](https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/blackberryworld/preparing_your_zip_file.html):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Release version="x.x.x.x">
       <ReleaseNotes>Release note text</ReleaseNotes>
       <filebundle name="MyAppNoTouchEnglish_4.6.0.0">
            <language>en</language>
       </filebundle>
       <filebundle name="MyAppNoTouchSpanish_4.6.0.0">
            <language>es</language>
       </filebundle>
       <filebundle name="MyAppTouchEnglish_4.7.0.0">
            <language>en</language>
       </filebundle>
       <filebundle name="MyAppTouchSpanish_4.7.0.0">
            <language>es</language>
       </filebundle>
       <filebundle name="MyAppTouchEnglish_6.0.0.0">
            <language>en</language>
       </filebundle>
       <filebundle name="MyAppTouchSpanish_6.0.0.0">
            <language>es</language>
       </filebundle>
</Release>
```

### Multi-Language Bundles

However, if there are **not** major differences between your app versions (English/Spanish), and you just want to let your code display text in the user's supported language, I would recommend [using the BlackBerry localization APIs](http://developer.blackberry.com/java/documentation/ui_localization_1988867_11.html).  These would allow one bundle to support both English and Spanish.  That way, you'd only need 3 bundles (MyAppNoTouch_4.6.0.0, MyAppTouch_4.7.0.0, and MyAppTouch_6.0.0.0).  [Here is a tutorial on this technique](http://blog.boris-wach.de/permalink/61).

If you do it this way, *if I remember correctly*, you simply don't include the `<language></language>` elements in release.xml, since each bundle supports both languages.

> Do I also need to add a suffix on each .cod file per bundle to support the languages that I need to support?

No, you don't **have** to, but that would actually be yet *another* way to handle this.  You can let one "Bundle" support English and Spanish.  Then, within that bundle, you can have different .cod files, which individually support English or Spanish:

```
 - MyApp_2.0
    - MyAppNoTouch_4.6.0.0
      - MyApp_en.cod
      - MyApp_es.cod
      - MyApp-1_en.cod
      - MyApp-1_es.cod
      - MyApp-2_en.cod
      - MyApp-2_es.cod
```

I haven't used this technique, personally.  It's just another way to achieve localization, but you don't have to do it this way.

### More

Also, see here for [some advice on localizing BB apps](https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/design/bb7/localization_2_0_514469_11.html).

Comment: Hi Nate, my app was actually supporting english and spanish using Localization. It uses the language that the device uses. So I just need 3 bundles on my .zip file right? And I don't need to add suffixes on my .cod? How about the release.xml? Thanks.

Comment: Correct, correct, and you probably dont need the zip file at all.  If you only have 3 bundles, then i agree with Peter that it's probably easier to just upload those three bundles by hand.

Comment: Thanks Nate. But my boss wants me to provide this, good thing it is all clearer now.

Comment: I understand.  A non-developer doing the upload is one reason to use the single zip file.  As I mentioned in the answer, I would add release.xml without the <language> xml elements.